# How do I define a custom command or a macro, or something of that nature, which will use the matrix environment?

Tags: matrices, delimiters, braces

When I write some latex with `\{` and `\}`, such as  the following:

> `\begin{Bmatrix} \dfrac{x_{1}}{10^{1}}, \dfrac{x_{2}}{10^{2}}, \dfrac{x_{3}}{10^{3}} \end{Bmatrix}`

The output looks like this:

[image: A JPEG IMAGE DISPLAYING THE CURLY BRACES THAT ARE TOO SHORT]

The curly braces are much too short.

I sometimes use the `Bmatrix` environment.

However, the source code becomes almost unreadable when I use the `Bmatrix` environment.

> `\begin{Bmatrix} \dfrac{x_{1}}{10^{1}}, \dfrac{x_{2}}{10^{2}}, \dfrac{x_{3}}{10^{3}} \end{Bmatrix}`

[image: A SCREEN CAPTURE JPEG OR PNG FILE BASED UPON USING Bmatrix to generate TALL CURLY BRACES]

Using `\dfrac` inside of curly-braces is not the problem. I use a lot of mathematical symbols inside of my sets. Sometimes, there are tall-shaped symbols inside of the set other than something similar to `\dfrac{1}{100}`.

How do I write my own custom latex-command, or latex-environment, so that the source code is highly-readable and the curly braces are nice and tall?

Comment: You mean `\left\{\dfrac{x_{1}}{10^{1}}, \dfrac{x_{2}}{10^{2}}, \dfrac{x_{3}}{10^{3}}\right\}`?

Comment: did you mean to post something else for the first code block? which is same as 2nd

Answer (score 2):

You did not show the code but presumably you used `\{...\}` instead of `\Bigl\{....\Bigr\}` but better to declare a paired delimiter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Set\{\}
\newcommand\xf[1]{\frac{x_{#1}}{10^{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Set*{\xf{1}, \xf{2}, \xf{3} }
\]

\end{document}
```